# How to deploy Express app with Vue Frontend in Vercel?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, vercel

I built the Vue app into a folder named dist.

I have backend APIs which are written in Node Express.

When I deploy it on Vercel, I'm getting 404 errors.

Here is my app structure & Vercel settings.

I'm new to Vercel, any help would be appreciated.

App Structure
[image]

`package.json`
[image]

`vercel.json`
[image]

Vercel Settings
[image]

Vercel Error:
[image]

Comment: Both Vue and Express apps are in the same folder?

Comment: As far as I know, vercel is not able to do SSR. If you want to host your Express app, you need a running Node.js instance. So, if you want to host both, you should rather go to Heroku or any kind of place where you can have a Node.js running VPS available.